# Tags (fun) and (fun-problem)

Tags: discussion, tagging

Can we please delete those tags?

The tags are subjective: fun problem? For whom?

Also these are meta tags: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: (fun) seems to be linked to (recreational-mathematics), and (fun-problem) seems to be tagged on 0 questions.  I think that tags with 0 question are automatically deleted after some fairly short period of time, but I might be wrong.  (I don't know whether this was the state of things when this question was asked.)

Comment: @Jonas: There were 4 question tagged fun-problem. I deleted those tags from those questions and then started this on meta. Did not realize the fun<->recreational-maths connection.

Comment: [There is a proposal to make (fun-problem) a synonym of (recreational-mathematics),](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/recreational-mathematics/synonyms) but it doesn't have enough votes. Also, wouldn't it be better to ask on meta *before* deleting tags?

Comment: I might agree, but I think you need to provide a bit more rationale and explanation, perhaps with some examples?

Comment: @Rahul: The tag was irrelevant to the question and subjective. Asking on meta before deleting tags (from questions, not the tags themselves) is just a huge waste of time for everyone.

Comment: @Jeff: Two words for you: meta tags.

Comment: @moron like I said, I don't disagree, but your Q was lacking in context for anyone reading.

Comment: @Moron: Fair enough. What rubbed me the wrong way initially was that it felt like someone decided they didn't like a tag and unilaterally removed it from all questions. But I trust your judgement.

Comment: @JEff: This was mainly a request for mods (maybe I should have tagged it feature-request/support, but didn't seem right), who I expect _know_ about the policy around meta tags. I do agree, having a context will help users unfamiliar with the policy understand the reason behind the request, as you can see I have already rubbed some folks the wrong way ;-)

Comment: I'm a little confused.  [fun] is not listed as a synonym for [recreational-mathematics] in the synonym menu, but it redirects to [recreational-mathematics] anyway.  [fun-problem] currently has no questions associated to it but is listed in the synonym menu as a synonym for [recreational-mathematics].  What's going on?

Comment: @Qiaochu: It seems to be there on the page for recreational-maths: http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/recreational-mathematics/synonyms

Comment: @Moron: ah, I was looking at the wrong menu.  Well, there doesn't seem to be a problem anymore.  [fun-problem] will either get deleted or added as a synonym (I don't really see the point of the latter) and [fun] is already a synonym.  Let me note, once again, that in the future such suggestions should go here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms

Comment: @Qioachu: That thread talks about mergers and synonyms. I am talking about deletion. Also, I don't agree with the fun<->recreational-maths synonym (and fun-problem too). I am guessing people will just tag problems they think are fun, which might not even be recreational-maths.Anyway...

Comment: I thought „recreational” means „fun”.